# Python AST: Parsing loop lengh using is missing line numbers

Tags: python, loops, parsing, size, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to parse line numbers of a loop using Python AST.
I am using ast.walk

```
for i in ast.walk(file):
    if isinstance(i,(ast.While,ast.For)):
       start=i.lineno;
       end=i.body[-1]
       while isinstance(end,(ast.While,ast.For,ast.If)):
          end = end.Body[-1]
```

What I am trying to do is offset my node, but when I get to something like;

> AttributeError: 'If' object has no attribute 'Body'.

I need this so I can get the line numbers from the start of the loop to the end.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `end.body` (lowercase)?

Comment: haha yes! you are right! I was up 3 hours in the night and spent all morning on a Typo :| thanks so much. How do I +1 your answer?

Comment: No +1 necessary.  I'm just happy to help :-)